My daughter lives with my ex, I bought her a phone and her dad takes it
My daughter lives with her dad. I bought her a cell phone he goes through it, goes through her messages. Ect. I have an iPhone I can see what she does what time it gets turned off ect. I can also see where it is and know if he has taken it away. Is it legal for him to tKe away property that I own. I live in texas

You don't have a legal problem, you have a co-parenting problem
Yes, it is legal for your daughter's father to control his child's access to technology. No, it would not be legal for him to keep the phone if you requested it back.
You need to talk and work out mutually agreeable boundaries and rules for the use of the phone. The law isn't going to be involved.

Funny a person asks a question in a tone to make her ex look like the bad person....   and the ex looked like he was at least trying to parent while the person asking the question is more worried about her phone than her daughter being parented.     This answer seems to be correct but personally I would add that her ability to monitor the phone has no bearing how the other parent should react to the phone usage - ESPECIALLY when her tone is she doesn't share all of these things she sees with him.    Dude got lucky getting out of that one.

@blankip this could be anything between "father wants the phone to be off by 1am and asked the 13 yo daughter to see messages sent by a 30yo 'friend'" and "father demands to be informed in real time of any communication between the 17yo daughter and her mother on any medium". I do not think we should read too much into a one-paragraph summary by a single party (nor would it be productive to ask further details).
